# InstallShield to modify web.config with user input

Tags: installshield

I have a task of creating an InstallShield for a .NET project.

I am using Flexera Software InstallShield (in case there are others)

To make a simple setup thing using install shield is fine.

The only problem is that I have to add a dialog box in between the wizard where I ask user for a number, which would go and replace a specific field in `web.config` file of the project.

I have been looking at the documentation on how to make a custom dialog but just unable to link the text box to a field in `web.config`.

Can anyone help me with some quick stuff ??

Comment: Which project type did you choose - Basic MSI or InstallScript? What have you tried so far? (e.g. editing dialogs, using the IIS view, XML File Changes or Text File Changes views)

Comment: i added an custom internal dialog, added a textbox to it and named the Property as PoolNumber.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is little late to answer this, but I had the same problem then i changed the name of property variable to all caps. Somehow that worked. I am working on InstallShield 2018.
Hope this helps to others who stumble upon the same problem.
Thanks.